# React, map and check if is empty or empty string not working for me

Tags: reactjs

I have some data that I run a map on to display. Before this I check if the data exists or not and if it does then loop through it and display. The issue I am having is the second map breaks when it hits empty string. The array it is looping through can be an array, single value or empty string. So I thought no big deal I will just check for those things but it always breaks when it hits empty string.

```
{assets.length && assets ?
        <StructuredListWrapper>
            <StructuredListHead>
                <StructuredListRow head>
                    {assetsHeadersList}
                </StructuredListRow>
            </StructuredListHead>
            <StructuredListBody>
            {assets.map(asset => (
                <StructuredListRow key={asset.id}>
                    <StructuredListCell>
                        <Link href={{
                            pathname: "/assets/editAsset",
                            query: {id: asset.id},
                        }}
                        >
                            <Button renderIcon={Edit32}>Edit
                            </Button>
                        </Link>
                    </StructuredListCell>
                    <StructuredListCell>
                        {asset.type}
                    </StructuredListCell>
                    <StructuredListCell>
                        <b>{asset.title}</b>
                    </StructuredListCell>
                    <StructuredListCell>
                        {asset.description}
                    </StructuredListCell>
                    <StructuredListCell>
                        {asset.segment}
                    </StructuredListCell>
                    <StructuredListCell>
                        {/*
                        *Check if tags exist
                        *loop through and display if exist
                         */}
                        {asset.tags && asset.tags.length && asset.tags !== " ?
                            asset.tags.map((tag, index) =>
                                <Tag style={style} type="blue" key={index}>{tag}
                                </Tag>
                            )   
                        :
                            <p>No Tags listed for this entry.</p>
                        }
                    </StructuredListCell>
                </StructuredListRow>
            ))}
            </StructuredListBody>
        </StructuredListWrapper>
        :
        <LoadingOverlay emptyResults={emptyResults}></LoadingOverlay>
        
        }
```

I thought this would have been simple enough to check for, but now I am confused on why this wont work. Any help would be great thanks!
I will show example of what the data can be.

```
tags: ""
tags: (17) ["video", "Harvard", "HBR", "new"]
tags: "data"
```

Those are the possibilities tags could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
{
   asset.tags &&
   typeof asset.tags === "object" &&
   asset.tags.length  ?
     asset.tags.map((tag, index) =>
       <Tag style={style} type="blue" key={index}>
         {tag}
       </Tag>
     )   
  :
    <p>No Tags listed for this entry.</p>
}
```

Condition flow:

- Check for assest.tags
- Look for typeof the tags
- Check the length

If all the three matches then use map to loop

Comment: I just ran this and it never pass, always skips the loop

Comment: @noobCoder There was typo in the code. It's fixed now. It's `object` not `Object`

Comment: ok that did help, it prevented it from breaking and works as expected. I just need to check if its a single string value now. Thanks for the help